# Mismatch between Java Jar Exit Code and Unix representation

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to return error code back to OS (Unix) using System.exit()
But everytime it is represented wrongly in Unix.

Say `System.exit(1)` is being represented as 256 when we do "$?" in unix.
`System.exit(2)`  is being represented as  when we do "$?" in unix.
`System.exit(3)`  is being represented as 768 when we do "$?" in unix.

Can anyone guide why is it so.

Comment: how are you running you java command and echo command?

Comment: It's really weird, because as far as I know, return codes in Unix takes values in 0-255 range: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: I am putting the code inside a jar. The jar is being executed in unix. once executed i am taking the exit code under variable "$?" and printing in console

Comment: Looks like exit code shifted 8 bits.

Comment: @JoopEggen Could be a possibility. But why such strange behaviour if that is true!

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: (far fetched) What about  reaching code inside `if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then ... fi` resp 0, 2, 3? It almost looks you have a UTF-16 charset conversion.

Comment: @JoopEggen, at least in `bash`, `-eq` is for arithmetic operations: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions.  Use `==` or `=` (POSIX `test`) for strings.

Comment: @ Anand Builders:  Please share the actual code.  How exactly are you reading $?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example how you could run the test on your system, to validate if you still get the same results.

**Foo.java**

```
package sub;
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("System.exit(%s)%n", args[0]);
        System.exit(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));
    }
}
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sub.Foo
```

**foo.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -d . Foo.java

jar cmf MANIFEST.MF foo.jar sub/Foo.class

for val in 1 2 3
do
  java -cp foo.jar sub.Foo $val
  echo "rc: sub.Foo $?"
  java -jar foo.jar $val
  echo "rc: main class in manifest $?"
  echo
done
```

**result here**

```
System.exit(1)
rc: sub.Foo 1
System.exit(1)
rc: main class in manifest 1

System.exit(2)
rc: sub.Foo 2
System.exit(2)
rc: main class in manifest 2

System.exit(3)
rc: sub.Foo 3
System.exit(3)
rc: main class in manifest 3
```